# Slow loading on RichTextBlock by long String

Tags: wpf, uwp, richtextbox, windows-10-universal

I have a `RichTextBlock` in my `UWP` project, when I set long string as it's content, it takes long to show content like 3 seconds. I searched the web and found because it does not have `virtualization`, it wants to render all content.
It seems that problem exist in WPF and RichTextBox.

Can you  suggest me what should I do to render just visual content?

Comment: how long is your string? i tested with 12000 character string and it renders instantly on a button press.

Comment: Use visual studio profiler to check what is taking that much time.. 3 seconds is too long.. also check if it makes any difference to run in release mode instead of debug.

Answer (score 1):

I would split the content by paragraphs and render each of them separetly in *ListView*.

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <RichTextBlock />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: I have a long paragraph not multiple

Comment: @Maryam Maybe you should not have one really long paragraph.

Comment: i was testing and i added as 36,000+ characters and it still rendered instantly..at 42000 character string it gave exception.. So there is something else slowing down the code

Comment: @HassaanAkbar , maybe the height of your RTB is static and it does not get as big as your content is, do u understand what I mean? if you set height of RTB as your content it gets slow

Comment: @HassaanAkbar, I have 60000 charachter

Comment: No I used RichTextBlock inside ScrollViewer.. Is it any book or something? 60,000 is too much anyways. for virtualization u need to divide it in small paragraphs.. And I don't think such a large RichTextBlock would look any user friendly.. Use headings and titles which opens on taping them.. like mobile site of wikipedia

Comment: @HassaanAkbar, if I divided it into small paragraph it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: Do u have images in `RichTextBlock`?

Answer (score 0):

Turn your long string into list of smaller strings `List<string> strList`. Whenever the ScollViewer reaches the end more text will be loaded(in the same paragraph).

```
    <ScrollViewer Name="Scroll"
          ViewChanged="Scroll_OnViewChanged">
        <StackPanel>
            <RichTextBlock>
                <Paragraph x:Name ="P"></Paragraph>
            </RichTextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

.

```
    private void Scroll_OnViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                var scroller = (ScrollViewer) sender;

                if (scroller.ScrollableHeight-scroller.VerticalOffset > 5) return;    
                if (pointer >= strList.Count) return;

                var run = new Run {Text = strList[pointer++]};

                P.Inlines.Add(run);
            }
```

`pointer` is just a private class field of type `int`.

Comment: because I have search page and maybe I want to go end of page, this is slow again.